# Can't sync repositoy from GitHub Mac client

Tags: macos, git, github

When I try to sync using the GitHub client for Mac, I get this message:

```
Authentication Failed
You may not have permission to access MyRepository.
Check Preferences to make sure you’re still logged in.
```

The preferences are ok. The URL of my project is:

```
ssh://git.mydomain.com/MyRepository
```

If I try to pull/push via command line IT WORKS! The problem is really with the GitHub client. It suddenly happened AFTER I changed my User password. I tried to clean up my keychain already, reinstall GitHub and some other things, but nothing worked so far.

How do I solve this problem? How can I have my GitHub client working again? Any hint?

**DETAIL:** This is NOT a GitHub project. I have my own git server. I am using just it as client in this case.

Comment: Same problem for me.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I can push and pull from command-line, but via Github Desktop it keeps failing authentication.  I see no prompt or setting to enter credentials.